# Creating an Enemy Class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've never done this before and my true understanding of classes are not that good. However, I plan on mastering it after this project! What I'd like to do is create a class to determine enemy type by TAG: Enemy1 or Boss. (I've already designed a system to randomize the Enemy1 stats so no two will be the same. However, here, I just want to learn how to properly setup enemies stats so here's my code)

```
using System.Collections;

public class Enemies : MonoBehaviour {

    public float MaxHp;
    public static float Hp;
    GameObject enemy = GameObject.Find("Enemy1");
    GameObject boss = GameObject.Find("Boss");

    void Awake()
    {
        AssignStats(enemy, MaxHp);
    }

    public static void AssignStats (GameObject en, float MaxHp)
    {

        if (en.tag == "Enemy1")
        {
            MaxHp = 50;
            Hp = MaxHp;
            Debug.Log(Hp);
        }

        if (en.tag == "Boss")
        {

            MaxHp = 500;
            Hp = MaxHp;
            Debug.Log(Hp);
        }
    }
}
```

This code doesn't seem to work. Why?

Comment: It's a bit unclear right now - what GameObject is this `Enemies` script currently attached to?

Comment: I have the script attached to a Red Sphere, which is the first enemy you would encounter; it simply jumps up and down. In the inspector, the script has maxHP: 0, so I can tell it isn't working... That and a few error messages saying something about cannot call function before something else.. Not sure .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Enemy Class : Enemy.cs (not Monobehavior)

```
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Enemy
{
     public EnemyType EnemyType;
     public GameObject EnemyPrefab;
     public string EnemyTag;
     public int MaxHealth;
     public int EnemyDamage;
     public Vector3 SpawnPos;

     private int _currentHealth;

public void Init()
{
    _currentHealth = MaxHealth;
}


public void UpdateHealth(int newHealthValue)
{
    _currentHealth = newHealthValue;
}

public void ReceiveDamage(int damage)
{
    var updatedHealth = _currentHealth - damage;
    UpdateHealth(updatedHealth > 0 ? updatedHealth : 0);
}
```

}

Enemies Class : Enemies.cs that manage all enemies, randomize between enemies

```
using UnityEngine;

public enum EnemyType
{
    Enemy1,
    Enemy2,
    Enemy3,
    Enemy4,
    Enemy5,
    Boss
}

public class Enemies : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Enemy[] AllEnemies;
    //Initial Value
    public int NumberOfEnemies = 3;

private void Start()
{
    InitEnemies(NumberOfEnemies);
}

public void InitEnemies(int howManyEnemies)
{
    for(int i= 0; i < howManyEnemies; i++)
    {
        var randomIndex = Random.Range(0, AllEnemies.Length - 1);

        SpawnEnemy(AllEnemies[randomIndex]);
    }
}

    public void SpawnEnemy(Enemy enemy)
    {
        Instantiate(enemy.EnemyPrefab, enemy.SpawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
        enemy.Init();
    }
}
```

You can see that I assigned all enemies data in the inspector that come up from the array of Enemy in enemies class, it has Enemy Prefab, position, damage etc.

If you have any question, feel free to ask :)

Cheers!

Comment: Is this to spawn random enemies or random enemy hp? Either way, this is very impressive code! I feel like printing it, framing it, and hanging it on a wall lol seriously! This is great!

Comment: Hehe thanks. It's adding random enemies  from AllEnemies Array that is predefined in the inspector. (see the picture)

Comment: Okay, so I decided to use your code as a general basis for designing my own code. Not only that, but I'm looking what you've done. There's a lot of research needed for me to fully comprehend everything you done here. Anyway, I really like your enum approach so I definitely kept that in the playbook! I can now attack and damage my enemies, but what I cannot do is figure out how to destroy them. How can I define the current enemies game object? My code is similar to your first suggestion where I can grab the type. But I cannot destroy the type.

Answer (score 2):

if I understand corrlcy.

you don't need to pass parameters to `AssignStats` method because the all you need property in the class.

I would use `gameObject.tag` to get the current append object tag.

- if you append to `Enemy1` component you will do `gameObject.tag == "Enemy1"` condition.
- if you append to `Boss` component you will do `gameObject.tag == "Boss"` condition.

you just append the script to your role component and tag right tag.

```
using System.Collections;

public class Enemies : MonoBehaviour {

    public float MaxHp;
    public float Hp;

    void Awake()
    {
        AssignStats();
    }

    public void AssignStats ()
    {

        if (gameObject.tag == "Enemy1")
        {
            MaxHp = 50;
            Hp = MaxHp;
            Debug.Log(Hp);
        }

        if (gameObject.tag== "Boss")
        {

            MaxHp = 500;
            Hp = MaxHp;
            Debug.Log(Hp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought at first too! However, when I remove the parameters, it gives me the ugly red line underneath which means it hates me lol :p

Comment: @TimDuval I know that you can try to use my edit answer. I guess the problem is about `static`, because when you write `static` method you need to let the property be `static` if you need to use them, so remove the `static` keyword can fix it.

Comment: How do I add an image into this comment box? I have it ready. Now does my function need to be static or just my variables? public static maxHP?

Comment: In your case, I think you don't need to use `static` method and property, because static mean all object share the data.

Comment: I was planning on creating an enemy damage class and reference..I'm not sure if I could make them non static and still inherit. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you mean you want to let `enemy` shard the damage?

Comment: I want this class to be accessed by another class later. I'm just not there yet, yanno?

Comment: @TimDuval check my answer below. Otherwise you can make an class called Enemy that contains all shared attributes between enemies ( like health , damage, damage block etc) and also put the declaration of methods like DealDamage() etc with virtual keyword before it and then create the specific class for example Hulk which inherit from Enemy class and override virtual methods with your need.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like that :

```
//enum contains all your enemies
public enum EnemyType
{
    Enemy1,
    Boss
}

public class Enemies : MonoBehaviour
{
    //This will be assigned in the inspector
    public EnemyType CurrentEnemyType;

    //You don't need them to be public since you are hardcoding them.
    private float MaxHp;
    private float Hp;

    void Awake()
    {
        AssignStats();
    }

    public void AssignStats()
    {
        if (gameObject.CompareTag(CurrentEnemyType.ToString()))
        {
            if (CurrentEnemyType == EnemyType.Enemy1)
            {
                MaxHp = 50;
                Hp = MaxHp;
                Debug.Log(Hp);
            }
            // instead of doing separated if blocks, you need to do if else for less code execution
            else if (CurrentEnemyType == EnemyType.Boss) 
            {
                MaxHp = 500;
                Hp = MaxHp;
                Debug.Log(Hp);
            }
        /*
         More simplified way instead of the if else, if you assume that all your enemies except the boss have 50 hp.

        MaxHp = CurrentEnemyType == EnemyType.Boss ? 500 : 50;
        Hp = MaxHp;
        Debug.Log(Hp);
        */

        }
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: I'm going to do some research on enums! This looks pretty awesome and useful! I'll give this a try, thanks!

Comment: Just a tidbit of info, I plan on randomizing regular enemies between 50-150HP and the bosses will be 500 everytime,except maybe the final boss. Additionally, there will be enemy2,3,4 etc... That's just what level they're on.However, I can reuse them on any stage, if the scheme matches.

Comment: @TimDuval wait a little bit I will try to add another answer with your request.

Comment: Awesome! I most certainly appreciate the help! I've already learned a lot from just one of your post! Nothing better than learning a new approach, even on the logic behind private/public variables. Thanks!

Comment: UnityException: You are not allowed to call this function when declaring a variable.
Move it to the line after without a variable declaration.
If you are using C# don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, Instead move initialization to the Awake or Start function.
Enemies..ctor ()

Comment: Yes, but it was because I didn't erase my Find() variables, I think. The problem was resolved after I erased them.